# Change backBarButtonItem color on current ViewController in iOS 6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, backbarbuttonitem

I have a UINavigationController (with a UITableView) inside of a UIPopoverController. When I select a row in the table view I push to a new UIViewController. This view has a navigation bar with a back button. Inside the view there is a button. When I touch this button I want the back button to change color. This needs to work in iOS 6. Is this possible without creating a custom button?

Here is what I have tried:

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    self.backButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Created a UIBarButtonItem outlet and connected it in IB 
}
```

Comment: is it a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, this view is pushed from a navigation controller

Comment: are you sure this method is being called? You could put a log statement or a breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, the method is being called.

Answer (score 3):

you could use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

in loadView or viewDidLoad

Comment: I need this to happen after the view is loaded

Comment: override viewWillAppear from UIViewController and add the code

Comment: If I put the code in viewWillAppear it will be called when the view loads. I need this to happen when I push a button, after the view is loaded.

Comment: This solution changes the color of the navigation bar along with the button. I just want the button to change color. It also doesn't work in a popover.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an outlet for the button then change the tint color

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIBarButtonItem *item;
```

and then

```
-(void)buttonClicked { //or whatever method gets called with the button click
item.tintColor =  [UIColor blueColor]; 
//or 
item.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

in the case of a navigation controller, you would just have to do

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: what do you mean methods?

Comment: tintColor? like the property

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant the two solutions you provided don't work. I edited my question with more detail of how my app is set up.